# How does one get the inbox folder and item count?

Tags: c#, outlook, mapi

I finally managed to work out how to create item counts of the inbox, sent items, calendar & contacts but I'm having problems with the folder count.

Let say I have 5 folders created in my mailbox and 2 sub folders in each folder. When I run this code, it counts 5 folders instead of all folders and sub folders which would equal 15 folder.

I'm guessing a foreach statement or something but I still a newb :-)

```
#region Run Item Count

Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace ns = null;

private void btnRunItemCount_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

    MAPIFolder oInbox = this.ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    tbInboxItemCount.Text = oInbox.Items.Count.ToString();
    MAPIFolder oSentItems = this.ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
    tbSentMailItemCount.Text = oSentItems.Items.Count.ToString();
    MAPIFolder oCalendar = this.ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
    tbCalendarItemCount.Text = oCalendar.Items.Count.ToString();
    MAPIFolder oContacts = this.ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);
    tbContactsItemCount.Text = oContacts.Items.Count.ToString();
    MAPIFolder oFolder = this.ns.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
    tbFolderItemCount.Text = oInbox.Folders.Count.ToString();
}

#endregion
```

Thanks for any help received! Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to recursively process all folders starting with Namespace.Folders.
Off the top of my head:

int allitems = CountFolders(ns.Folders);
...
private int CountFolders(Folders folders)
{
    int c = folders.count;
    foreach (MAPIFolder folder in folders)
    {
        c += CountFolders(folder.Folders);
    }
    return c;
}

Comment: Hi Dmitry! This code ALMOST worked a treat, however, it counts all folder including those in my PST file. Do you know how to make in only count the folders with the default mailbox? thanks!

Comment: You can start with the top of the default store if you retrieve the root folders collection using Namespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Parent.Folders